# Add track to the Audirvana play queue using (Apple)Script on macOS

Tags: macos

I try to add tracks to the Audirvana play queue with an external program on macOS (beside DnD). My idea was to use AppleScript as it is possible to get the current playing track with the following code:

```
tell application "Audirvana"
    set x to playing track url
end tell
```

Maybe adding songs to play queue (and also getting the content of the play queue) is also possible with AppleScript. Other solutions are welcome as well.

The following works:

```
set fn to "file://%2FUsers%2Fxxx%2Ftest.flac"
tell application "Audirvana"
    set playing track type AudioFile URL fn
end tell
```

It replaces the current playing song.

The following works as well:

```
set fn to "file://%2FUsers%2Fxxx%2Ftest.flac"
tell application "Audirvana"
    set next track type AudioFile URL fn
end tell
```

This one deletes the play queue and replaces the next song to play.

But I am looking for a solution that **appends** a song the play queue.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow. You should add a bit more information to your question, specifically: What have you tried, what happened, and what were you expecting to happen? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more info on how to form a good question.

Comment: I have looked at the Audirvana Dictionary with the ScriptEditor. It seams that appending to the play queue is not supported at all.